# SQL - how can I avoid a concurrency conflict on this UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table.  Multiple external processes will be simultaneously looking at it & updating it.

I want to write some SQL to update "the one row with the highest PRIORITY, which has not already been updated (by another external process)".

The processes access my table using the SQL below.  But my fear is... I'm not sure what will happen if two processes attempt to run this code *at nearly the same time*.  Is there some risk that two *nearly simultaneous* instances of this code will both try to update the same row?

I just want to be sure that the code, as written (using a CTE) runs the SELECT and UPDATE in a single transaction, with no chance of multiple processes selecting & updating the same row.  If that's not already the case, then let me know what I'd need to change to accomplish this.

Thanks!

```
WITH MostUrgentWorkAssignment AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM 
        dbo.WorkAssignments a       
    WHERE
        a.UserID IS NULL
    ORDER BY 
        a.Priority
)
UPDATE MostUrgentWorkAssignment 
SET UserID = @UserID
```

Comment: I haven't tried this in this context, but I would assume adding query hints UPDLOCK + HOLDLOCK should prevent several processes accessing the same row.

Comment: Yes you can update a cte when the cte contains only a single base table.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that TSQL be something like this, avoiding the unnecessary CTE?

```
UPDATE [dbo].[WorkAssignments] 
    SET
           [UserId] = @UserID
    FROM
           [dbo].[WorkAssignments] [A]
        JOIN
           (
               SELECT TOP 1
                           [A].[Id]
                   FROM 
                           [dbo].[WorkAssignments] [A]       
                   WHERE
                           [A].[UserId] IS NULL
                   ORDER BY 
                           [A].[Priority]
           ) [MostUrgentWorkAssignment]
               ON [MostUrgentWorkAssignment].[Id] = [A].[Id];
```

If you have a sensible [Isolation Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) this statement will be safe. The select and update will run within an implicit transaction as they are part of the same statement. I suspect this is equally true, with or without the CTE.

Comment: I cannot see any difference in this approach as compare to the one OP has used, CTE and the UPDATE from results returned from CTE is `ONE STATEMENT`, under any isolation level  an update statement will obtain `exclusive locks` on the row and will not be visible to other users unless a user tries to access rows with `READ Uncommitted` isolation level. You have used a bit different syntax but the implications are the same in either of the cases.

Comment: @M.Ali, agreed, as I say in my answer.

Comment: It sounds like you're both agreeing that my original code already does what I want.  @M.Ali - put it in an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: @Jodrell - Is there a reason we'd want to avoid the CTE?  I kind of like it, it's a concise way to get the job done.